# UITabBar tint color not working on images

Tags: ios8, uitabbar, uiappearance

I have a `UITabBar` set up with Interface Buider and the image highlighting works correctly only if I don't set the global app tint color:

[image: tab bar without tint color]

When I set the global tint color of my app using

```
[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[TAStyleKit tintColor]];
```

then all the tab images appear as selected.

[image]

Only when I click on the tab and go back again, they have the correct color. Note the "Weapons" tab which is here grey:

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT**: Never mind what I wrote before, looks like you just need to change the following...

```
[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[TAStyleKit tintColor]];
```

To...

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[TAStyleKit tintColor]];
```

Notice that you were trying to change the appearance of UIView instead of UITabBar. I ran this in a project and it did the trick.

[image]

[image]

**Swift 4.0**

`UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.red` or `TAStyleKit.tintColor`

Comment: I have just one image per tab and I do want the tint color to be applied on the image

Comment: I deleted everything I wrote and wrote a solution that should accomplish what you're looking for. You were setting the appearance of UIView instead of UITabBar.

Comment: i'm setting the tint on `UIView` because I want all of my ui elements to have this tint color instead of the defaut blue one.

Comment: My suggestion to you, while not the most convenient, would be to set the global tint color on all of your views that support UIAppearance (mostly UIView subclasses). There is a known issue with selectedImageTintColor that has yet to be addressed, which is what you are seeing when setting the UIView tint color. So if all you have is a tab bar, nav bar, segmented control, etc... it should only be adding a few lines to your code. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Here is may be a better one, when you can't or don't want to delete the basic UIView.tintColor code. Just set the tintColor on UIViews inside the tab bar to the default gray color.

```
let view = UIView.appearance()
view.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()

let viewsInTabBar = UIView.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UITabBar.self])
viewsInTabBar.tintColor = UIColor(white: 144.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1) // default gray for inactive items

let tabBar = UITabBar.appearance()
tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.redColor() // actual highlight color
```

unfortunately, apple does not use one of its standard gray values...

Answer (score 2):

It can also be set directly from Storyboard[XCode 10.1] by setting Image Tint for UITabBar
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `SwiftUI`. The above appearance technique won't work. Use `.tint` modifier on your `TabView`.

```swift
TabView(
  ...
)
.tint(Color.red)
```

Note that the API is `.accentColor` on older SwiftUI versions